# Find a scalar to make a vector addition positive

Tags: vector, max, linear-algebra

I have two vectors a=(a_1, a_2,...,a_n) and b=(b_1, b_2,...,b_n). I want to find a scalar "s" such that s=max{s : a+sb >= 0}. Here inequality is elementwise i.e. a_i+sb_i>=0 for all i=[1,...,n]. How to compute such a scalar ? Also if s=infinity is the solution, we will bound s by s=1.

Also vector "a" is nonnegative (i.e. each element is >=0).

Comment: vector a has nonnegative entries, and b?

Comment: There is no restriction on elements of b. They can be negative.

Comment: @AGNGazer not entirely true, a+sb >= is always true for s=0.
I'm more concerned with cases where b is entirely positive, because that implies s=inf.

So what exactly do you mean by "how to compute" anyways? You can compute elementwise the domains where the inequality holds, intersect them and take the upper bound of that (for example)

Comment: @Banana: Thanks. I modified the question for infinity case. Can you explain your approach using some algorithm or example.

Comment: I added pseudocode for an easy algorithm as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so with a_i >= 0, we can see that s=0 is always a solution.
One possible way is to solve the inequality on all components and then take the intersection of the domains. Their upper bound (which, if finite, is part of the intersection) is then your wanted number.
that means:

[image: inequalities]

is what you're trying to solve. Note that, because in the second case b_i is negative, the number on the right hand side is positive. That means the intersection of all s_i you get like this is non-empty. The maximum has a lower bound of 0, so technically you can *ignore the inequalities where b_i is positive*, they are true anyways. But, for completeness and illustration purposes:

**Example**:
a= (1,1), b=(-0,5,1)

1. 1 - s*0.5 >= 0 , that means s <= 2, or s in (-inf, 2]
2. 1 + s*1 >= 0, that means s>= -1, or s in [-1,inf)

intersection: [-1,2]
That means the maximum value such that both equations hold is 2.

That is the most straight-forward way, of course there are probably more elegant ways.

**Edit:** As algorithm: check if b_i is positive or negative. If positive, save s_i = 1 (if you want your value to be bound by one). If negative, save s_i = -a_i/b_i. In the end you want to actually take the minimum!

But **more efficient**: You don't actually need to care when b_i is positive. Your maximum will be greater or equal than zero anyways. So just check the cases where it is smaller than 0 and keep the minimum of them -a_i/b_i, as that is the upper bound of the region.

**Pseudocode**:

```
s = 1
for i in range = 1 to length(b):
    if b[i]<0:
        s = min(s, -a[i]/b[i])
```

Why the minimum? Because that -a[i]/b[i] is the upper bound of the region.